# Solve $ u_{xx}=x^2 u_{yy}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, canonical-transformation

I am trying to solve the following PDE: 
$$ u_{xx}=x^2 u_{yy} $$
I thought it is much easier to consider its canonical form, so I used the change of variable and got my new equation:

$$  u_{vw}=\frac{1}{v-w}(u_v-u_w) $$
But even this seems a bit difficult for me. Can any one help me solving my equation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I know very little about solving PDEs, but this seems like a good candidate for separation.

Comment: Than you for your answer  @CharlesHudgins, would you please  help me how to use separatuion ?

Comment: What are your boundary conditions?

Comment: No boundary conditions are given @maxmilgram

Comment: How do you expect a solution then?

Answer (score 3):

$$u_{xx}=x^2u_{yy}$$
This is the continuation of the Charles Hudgins's answer.
$$
\frac{X''(x)}{x^2X(x)} = \frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)}=K=\lambda^2
$$
With $\lambda$ real or complex. Note that setting $K=\lambda^2$ doesn't reduce the generality insofar $\lambda$ can be complex. This setting is in interest of simpler typing (avoiding square roots).

$Y''(y)-\lambda^2 Y(y)=0\quad$ gives $$ Y=c_1e^{\pm\lambda y}$$
which includes the sinusoidal cases when $\lambda$ is complex.

$X''(x)-\lambda^2x^2X(x)=0\quad$ gives 
$$X=c_2x^{1/2}I_{\pm 1/4}\left(\frac12\lambda x^2\right)$$
This involves the Modified Bessel function of the first kind $I_\nu(z)$ .
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html

A family of particular solutions of the PDE is :
$$u=C\,x^{1/2}I_{\pm 1/4}\left(\frac12\lambda x^2\right)e^{\pm\lambda y}$$
Any linear combination of particular solutions is solution of the PDE. Thus on discret form :
$$u(x,y)=\sum_{\forall\lambda} C_\lambda\,x^{1/2}I_{\pm 1/4}\left(\frac12\lambda x^2\right)e^{\pm\lambda y}$$
where $C_\lambda$ are arbitrary constants, to be determined according to some boundary condition.

Or on integral form :
$$u(x,y)=\int C(\lambda)\,x^{1/2}I_{\pm 1/4}\left(\frac12\lambda x^2\right)e^{\pm\lambda y}d\lambda$$
where the function $C(\lambda)$ is arbitrary, to be determined according to some boundary condition.

Of course this is very complicated in general. But simplification might occur in some cases of favourable boundary conditions allowing to reduce to a limited number of standard functions. That is why it is very important that the boundary conditions be known.

Answer (score 2):

I want to preface by saying that all of my PDE solving knowledge comes from the physics courses I took, so hopefully someone more knowledgeable can post a more complete answer.

That said, this seems like a good candidate for solving by separation. Consider solutions of the form
$$
u(x,y) = X(x) Y(y)
$$
Plugging this into the PDE, we find
$$
X''(x)Y(y) = x^2 X(x)Y''(y)
$$
Divide through by $X(x)Y(y)$. We have
$$
\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)} = \frac{x^2 Y''(y)}{Y(y)}
$$
Rearranging a little bit, this means
$$
\frac{X''(x)}{x^2X(x)} = \frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)}
$$
The left hand side depends only on $x$ and the right hand side depends only on $y$. This is only possible if both sides are equal to some constant $K$. Thus
$$
\frac{X''(x)}{x^2X(x)} = K \quad \quad \frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)} = K
$$
This yields the system of ordinary differential equations $X'' = K x^2 X$ and $Y'' = KY$. At this point we need to know the boundary conditions on $u(x,y)$ to determine the solutions to these differential equations. Suppose we knew the boundary conditions and found families of solutions $x_n$ and $y_n$ for the $X$ and $Y$ equations respectively.

For reasons I don't understand (again, someone please supplement this answer or provide a different more complete answer) any solution $u$ of the PDE will be of the form
$$
u= \sum_{n,m} a_{mn} x_n y_n
$$
where the $a_{mn}$ are constants.